# Debug a crashing IE11

Tags: javascript, crash, internet-explorer-11, crash-reports

I have some Javascript code which makes IE11 to crash. How can I find out the offending code? (function name, line number, stack trace, whatever)

The only option I see is

> debug with VS2015

but this goes to far telling me the hex offset in the DLL (mshtml.dll) where the exception was raised

that's the error report from VS2015:

> Unhandled exception at 0x62E06A9C (mshtml.dll) in iexplore.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000028.

Comment: any solution or workarounds?

Comment: the "solution" I found was to upgrade to the Javascript library responsible for the crash (D3, https://d3js.org/). The crash simply dissappeared. But yes, IE11 still sucks big time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "solution" I found was to upgrade to the Javascript library responsible for the crash (D3, d3js.org). The crash simply dissappeared

But yes, IE11 still sucks big time